# I want to read data from a text file and transform it into list of transactions

Tags: python

I have a text file with data and I want to read this data to a list.

[image]

I have tried this code, it covert it into list but it adds a double quotations around each line

```
file = 'filepath'
data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file)]
```

Instead of double quotes around each line I want round brackets "(" around each line

[image]

Comment: What does the data from the file look like?

Comment: Please give a part of the example data file in a text format here.

Comment: 'looking', 'website', 'created', 'matter', 'use', 'create', 'must', 'designed', 'tutor', 'offering', 'membership', 'plans', 'customers', 'able', 'purchase', 'book', 'sessions', 'please', 'send', 'budget', 'lowest', 'offer', 'likely', 'message', 'questions', 'made',

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if quotes in your txt file are a desired behaviour.
If file is:

```
'looking', 'website'
'ciao', 'hello'
```

and you want a list of tuples:

```
file = 'filepath'
data = [tuple([x.strip()[1:-1] for x in line.rstrip('\n').split(",")]) for line in open(file)]
>>> data

[('looking', 'website'), ('ciao', 'hello')]
```

or use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
import ast

data = [ast.literal_eval(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in open(file)]
```

---

if your output is a list of strings, simply add parenthesis:

```
data = ["(" + line.rstrip('\n') + ")" for line in open(file)]
>>> data

["('looking', 'website')", "('ciao', 'hello')"]
```

Comment: almost there as double quotes are gone and "(" are there but it output each word / item to next line like [('looking',
  'website',
  'created',
  'matter',

Comment: is your output a string or a `list`? a list of strings `"('eggs', 'bacon')"`?

Comment: actually I want to make transactions to be processed by apriori algorithm and the form should be [('item1','item2','item3'),('item2','item3')]

Comment: Is `[('item1','item2','item3'),('item2','item3')]` a string or a list? if it's a list, is `('item2','item3')` a string or a tuple? Can't help if you don't give this infos

Comment: check update. look that double quotes are a notation to identify a string object, and are not part of the string itself